# How to deploy multiple models to an endpoint using Azure Machine Learning CLI v2?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

At the GA of [az ml cli v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/azure-machine-learning-release-notes-cli-v2#2022-05-24), we've been working on some POC using [yml online deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-yaml-deployment-managed-online) on top of managed endpoint and it all went well for single model, until when there's certain scenario where there is requirement to deploy multiple trained and registered models to one managed endpoint, it seems there is no documentations on how to achieve that.

Previously using Python SDK, it was able to deploy list of models to AKS cluster.

Checking if there's any limitation or could be some docs I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

This operation can be performed using ACI (Azure Container Instance). According to [Blackmist](https://github.com/Blackmist)  [sdgilley](https://github.com/sdgilley) mention in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-azure-container-instance). There is a deployment limit of 1000 models per deployment per container.

The procedure of deployment was shown syntax based in the documentation provided.

**Updated:**

The above link is with respect to V1, The below link with the procedure is regarding V2

Link for [V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints#use-more-than-one-model-in-a-deployment)

Comment: this is CLI v1, i am looking for CLI v2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I have updated the link for V2. Kindly check it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, I've came across the v2 docs too, but it does not specify how to deploy multiple model into a single real-time endpoint